# Добавлять тег <br> перед определенным словом если оно присутствует

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Если в блоке price присутствует предлог "до", то необходимо добавлять перед ним тег br для переноса на новую строку. Как это можно реализовать? Контент в блоке может быть разным.

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>500</i> до <i>1000</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>800</i> до <i>1800</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      <i>700</i> <span>руб.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если в блоке price присутствует предлог "до", то необходимо добавлять перед ним тег br

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(o => {
  o.innerHTML = o.innerHTML.replace(/\sдо\s/g, '<br />до ')
})
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>500</i> до <i>1000</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>800</i> до <i>1800</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      <i>700</i> <span>руб.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. На много короче моего :)

Comment: Благодарю за решение.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".price").forEach((item) => {
  let itemHTML = item.innerHTML;
  if (itemHTML.includes("до")) {
    let i = itemHTML.indexOf("до");
    item.innerHTML = itemHTML.substring(0, i) + "<br>" + itemHTML.substring(i);
  }
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>500</i> до <i>1000</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>800</i> до <i>1800</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      <i>700</i> <span>руб.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант, но без использования регулярных выражений:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach( elem => {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.split(' до ').join('<br/>до ');
})
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 32%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>500</i> до <i>1000</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      от <i>800</i> до <i>1800</i> <span>руб.</span>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
      <meta itemprop="price">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="price">
      <i>700</i> <span>руб.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```